# How SwingWork works with EDT?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread

Well, i have the following code bellow that works fine, but i wanna understand how works the threads in this code.

```
private void jLabelInicioMovimentacaoMouseClicked(
            java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {// GEN-FIRST:event_jLabelInicioMovimentacaoMouseClicked     

        jStatusBar1.setWaitState(false);
        jStatusBar1.setWaitStartMessage("Pesquisando...");
        jStatusBar1.setWaitState(true);

        this.sw = new SwingWorker() {

            @Override
            public Object construct() {
                try {
                    jGDataTextFieldDataInicial
                            .setValue(retornarPrimeiroDiaMovimentacao());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JGOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FFormMain.this,
                            "Ocorreu um erro nas bibliotecas",
                            JGOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void finished() {
                jStatusBar1.setWaitStartMessage("Finalizado");
                jStatusBar1.setWaitState(false);
            }
        };
        sw.start();

    }// GEN-LAST:event_jLabelInicioMovimentacaoMouseClicked
```

So, my idea is: When I execute the `jStatusBar1.setWaitState(false) (first line);` this code is executed in EDT (Event Dispatcher Thread) instantly, and the others lines too.

But when I execute `this.sw = new SwingWorker()...` I am creating a new Thread (outside of EDT), when this "Outside Thread" finish, the method "finished()" is called from EDT and the jStatusBar1 is updated.

My concept is right ?

Comment: please how to answering your question, seems like as you never read Oracle tutorial, please do you understand for why reason is SwingWorker in Swing APIs, how works, etc ...

Comment: What is that `SwingWorker` class you are using ? The one in the JDK does not have a `finished` nor a `construct` method